# Is there a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the closed form of
 $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
 as a function of $x$ and $n$?

Knowing that it converges to $e^x$ when $n\to \infty$.

Comment: It's a Taylor polynomial of $e^x$, so you can use the integral form of the remainder (this way you just get the answers below)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Denoting this by $f_n(x)$, we get $f_n'-f_n=-x^n/n!$, solving this differential equation we have $(f_n(x)e^{-x})'=-x^n e^{-x}$, thus taking into account initial condition $f_n(0)=0$ we get integral representation $$f_n(x)=e^x-\frac1{n!}e^x\int_0^x t^n e^{-t}dt.
$$
This may be further rewritten as $$f_n(x)=\frac1{n!}e^x\int_x^\infty t^n e^{-t}dt,$$
this is what is called incomplete Gamma function, see joro's answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5Ek%2Ffactorial%28k%29+k+from+0+to+n) it is related to the incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(a,x)$ and equals $$\frac{e^x\Gamma(n+1,x)}{n!}$$